# developer console not functioning properly

Tags: developer-console

My developer console is not functioning, failing to load logs and I cannot select drop downs etc. I have followed details of peoples answers (and SF answer). One particular answer which seems to be the official route is to log in to workbench/rest and run some queries. I have done that but I get 8 workspace id's back - are these other user's work spaces? thanks for looking.
[image]

Comment: Developer Console typically lags when log files of large sizes are to be loaded into the logs panel.

Comment: There is one hack try to open the dev console in the same window by copy the URL and paste in the same window. Also always do open resource not open. let me know if that works. also use chrome and keep less number of windows open. This some time won't work due to extensions installed so disable the extension you don't need or use.

Comment: thanks Avijit. I will try later

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps that are mentioned in salesforce official documentation https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000332898&type=1&mode=1

Steps with workbench

> 1. Login to Workbench and go to REST Explorer
> 2. Use the following query in Workbench to get the IDEWorkspace 
>      /services/data/v31.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT id, name from IDEWorkspace
>      ID of IDEWorkspace is "1dexxxxxxxxxxxxxx".
> 3. Do GET operation for the found id with following query "/services/data/v29.0/tooling/sobjects/IDEWorkspace/1de1a0000014sEWAAY"
> 4. You will see the content of IDEWorkspace
> 5. Do DELETE operation on found record.
> 6. Re-open Developer Console.
> 7. Developer Console will work fine. As we created a new workspace and the old workspace has been deleted.And the slowness will also be removed.

Regarding workspaces from https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/developer_console/developer_console_intro

> If you’re working on two different projects, you can have the related code, tests, and logs open simultaneously in separate workspaces. For instance, say you’re writing code to update some records for your engineering team, but you also want to check the system details for your navigation team. You can create two workspaces, each of which contains only the resources relevant to the project. Workspaces reduce clutter and make it easier to navigate between different resources.

I made a quick check on my dev Org by creating a new workspace for another user of my Org and could see that the **other user's workspace is also reflecting** with the query /services/data/v31.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT id, name from IDEWorkspace ID. Note: There is a default workspace for each user(in this case 2 as there are two users) See pic below
[image]

Comment: thank you. As mentioned, with regards to step 2 above - I get 8 work spaces returned from query - are these all mine?

Comment: The query returns even other users' workspaces. I have edited my answer with more information on my Dev org repro. Hope this helps

Comment: thanks again Swetha. I have edited my post to show 12 returns - how do I identify those work spaces as mine?

Comment: You can use something like /services/data/v31.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT+id,+name,+userid+from+IDEWorkspace and check which workspaces belong to your userId in your Org

Comment: ok will try. thanks

Comment: HI @user2382031 Just checking if you have any other queries or if this thread can be closed

Comment: hi Swetha, I followed your instructions but it didn't seem to work immediately. However, after logging in after the weekend. My dev console is back! thank you